# org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm trying to implement chat (1 to 1 & Group) in my Android Application using XMPP Server (Openfire) but, while connection I'm getting following exception 
"**org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException**" on following line

"**connection.connect();**"

I checked MyConstants.HOST, MyConstants.PORT, MyConstants.SERVICE are correct but don't know why I'm getting this error.

Following is my code so far, please check and help me to resolve this issue.

```
// Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(MyConstants.HOST, MyConstants.PORT, MyConstants.SERVICE);
        connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        connConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

        try
        {
            connection.connect();
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+connection.getHost());

            if(connection.isConnected())
            {
                Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                attributes.put("username", userId);
                attributes.put("password", MyConstants.PASSWORD);
                Registration reg = new Registration();
                reg.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
                reg.setTo(connection.getServiceName());
                reg.setAttributes(attributes);

                connection.sendPacket(reg);

                connection.login(userId, MyConstants.PASSWORD);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());
                //Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);                   
                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
                {
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
                    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                    if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
                }
            }

        } 
        catch (XMPPException ex) 
        {
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            connection = null;
        } 
        catch (SmackException e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception: ", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("Exception: ", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: please confirm port number.

Comment: Tulsiram Rathod I checked HOST, PORT, SERVICE are 100% correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue before, make sure you are not interchanging MyConstants.HOST, MyConstants.PORT

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
Roster.setRosterLoadedAtLoginDefault(false);

Answer (score -1):

I use the older version of Smack in my project but please refer to this, maybe it will help you.

In openfire i have created example user which login is userName, pass is password.

### The code below will throw similar exception like your:

```
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setServiceName(serviceName)
            .setHost(serverAddress)
            .setPort(serverPort)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(debugMode);

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    connection.connect();
```

Results in:

```
  org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): a0c88176-be28-4318-acb7-d08fd3803ef5@conference.makowka/jacek, StanzaTypeFilter:       org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence).
  org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): a0c88176-be28-4318-acb7-d08fd3803ef5@conference.makowka/jacek, StanzaTypeFilter: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence).
```

### But after transformation to this:

```
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setServiceName(serviceName)
            .setHost(serverAddress)
            .setPort(serverPort)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(debugMode);

    config.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, password);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    connection.connect().login();
```

Everything works nice! So please try to create user, set this user in config instance and call login method. So the key to solve is here:

```
    connection.connect().login();
```

Hope it will help you! :-)